# js removeChild does not work

Tags: javascript, removechild

I have had a bit tricky idea to dynamically create and remove elements. If user clicks the last element, then new element is created. I he clicks any other except the last element, then all elements with bigger id`s are removed. Here is [the example](http://help.andreyputilov.ru/test/).

This code works perfectly until I remove one element. It does not depend on the way I remove element, if I do this in Firebug or by pressing the last element the code also stops working. But when I add an element by add_button() function, the code again begins to work. And if I remove any element again, the code stops working as above.

Here is the sample code

```
function add_or_remove( id ) {
    var el = document.getElementById('box');
    // let`s check if this is the last button or not
    var last = true;
    var els = el.childNodes;
    for( var i in els )
        if( (els[i].nodeType==1) && (els[i].className) && (els[i].className.indexOf('button')>=0) )
            last = last && (els[i].id<='button_'+id);
    if( last ) {
        add_button();
    } else {
        remove_buttons_after( id );
    };
};

function add_button() {
    var el = document.getElementById('box');
    var id = add_button.id_new;
    var add = document.createElement('a');
    add.className = 'button';
    add.id = 'button_'+id;
    add.href='javascript: add_or_remove(\''+id+'\');';
    add.innerHTML = 'click me!';
    el.appendChild(add);
    add_button.id_new++;
}

function remove_buttons_after( id ) {
    var el = document.getElementById('box');
    var els = el.childNodes;
    var dels = [];
    for( var i in els )
        if( (els[i].nodeType==1) && (els[i].className) && (els[i].className.indexOf('button')>=0) )
            if( els[i].id>'button_'+id )
                dels.push( els[i] );
    for( i=0; i<dels.length; i++ )
        el.removeChild( dels[i] );
};
```

I can`t even imagine any reason for it.

Comment: how do you pass the id?

Comment: the generated code is
    <a class="button" id="button_1" href="javascript: add_or_remove('1');">click me!</a>
though the id is passed here

Comment: wow, I`ve just found out that it is working in a such strange manner in my browser only. I have Debian OS with Firefox 3.6, but the code has no modern techniques and should work in every old browser